# Why does showkey show a different keycode compared to xev?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Looking for an answer I came across [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49650/how-to-get-keycodes-for-xmodmap). There's something like this:

> The keycode X uses and the keycode the kernel uses are OFF BY 8 for "historical reasons". So take 97 - 8 = 89 and use 89 with the setkeycodes command (again as root):

Does anyone know what the historical reasons are and why the codes differ by 8?

Comment: For some reason, GitHub copilot created a link to here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The X11 protocol [defines a keycode as a 8-bit value in the range [8,255]](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#Keyboards).  The value 0 is a special value for AnyKey - I don't remember if anything uses 1-7, or they were simply reserved for future special cases.